# Error accessing binary data from a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary-data

I'm pretty new to python, using python 2.7.  I have to read in a binary file, and then concatenate some of the bytes together.  So I tried

```
f = open("filename", "rb")
j=0
infile = []
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        infile.append(byte) 
        byte = f.read(1)
finally:
    f.close()
blerg = (bin(infile[8])<<8 | bin(infile[9]))
print type
```

where I realize that the recast as binary is probably unnecessary, but this is one of my later attempts.

The error I'm getting is TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as index.
This is news to me, since I'm not using a string anywhere.  What the !@#% am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  Full traceback 
    file binaryExtractor.py, line 25, in 
    blerg = (bin(infile[8])<<8 | bin(infile[9]))
    TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as index

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Also, the indentation is off in the code. And `type` is a builtin function (or builtin type), so it's better not to use it as variable name.

Comment: "since I'm not using a string anywhere": `bin` returns a string, though.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I didn't realize bin return a string, I though it gave back the binary format as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `ord` function which returns an integer from a single character string, not `bin` which returns a string representation of a binary number.

Comment: Oops, hope you didn't see this answer before I applied my Ninja fix.

Comment: I did.  Then I refreshed it and was very happy.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) whenever possible instead of writing your own code for this.

```
>>> struct.unpack('<H', '\x12\x34')
(13330,)
```